# Drag & drop images from a HTA file

Tags: image, hta

From a HTML application (`.hta file`), you can drag any image and drop it into the desktop for example.

Does anybody know how to disable this capability?

I want the `.hta` files to have the same behavior as the `.html` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `ondragstart="return false;"` event handler to your images and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who renames your HTA file to an HTML file will be able to save the images.